# What is: Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException - How to continue to break on exception but this one?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, break

I'm using the CodePlex library NCalc and I'm getting the exception:

Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException

I expected an exception because I know my expression is not valid but I wonder where does that exception come from and how to mark it as "not break" in the "Exception" window of "Debug" menu. But I still want to break on all other exception.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These exceptions are thrown by the ANTLR Runtime Library when it detects an error in the input.

If you install the [ANTLR Language Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f) extension for Visual Studio, it will add the ANTLR-specific exception types to the **Exceptions...** dialog, and you can configure them as you would configure any others.

Comment: Thanks so much... I didn't know about that lib. I will have to take a look on that!

Comment: I wonder if you know if there is a project, or lib, which give me the possibility to include a similar edit window with ANTLR support as Visual Studio (syntax highlighting, autocomplete, ...) into my own program ?